# How to start Cyberghost and select country IP Address, and auto-change IP Address after a period of time, by Windows Command Line?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, proxy, command

How to connect Cyberghost by Windows Command Line. I want something like this:

```
Cyberghost.exe /Connect /Country United States
echo Countdown Timer for 30 Minutes
TIMEOUT /T 1800 /NOBREAK
Cyberghost.exe /Disconnect
Cyberghost.exe /Connect /Country United Kingdom
echo Countdown Timer for 30 Minutes
TIMEOUT /T 1800 /NOBREAK
Cyberghost.exe /Disconnect
Pause
```

Thanjk youuuuuuuuuuuuu so much for ur answers, solve answers, if this is imposibble, then at least what are the alternatives softwares or methods.

Comment: This depends if CyberGhost has command line flags....